# Joomla Form field type sql="....WHERE condition"?

Tags: sql, forms, joomla, components, field

In Joomla 2.5, how can I do a form field type "SQL" with the condition "WHERE" in the SQL query?

Example:

```
<field name="catid" type="sql" query="SELECT id, title FROM #__table WHERE {condition}" />
```

There isn't anything about this in the joomla docs. I've found this link but it doesn't refer anything of using a WHERE condition in the SQL query ( http://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type).

Can someone please tell me if this is possible or not to do in Joomla?

I have a table with products and a table with shops associated to brands. If I edit one shop I would like to show a combobox with all the products from the brand of the shop. Is that possible? SELECT * FROM #__products WHERE brand = {the brand id associated to the shop I selected for edit} Is this possible?

I was able to do this with a custom form field =)

http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Thank you RHR for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible

My code which i used

```
<fields name="request">
 <fieldset name="request" >
<field name="id" type="sql" query="SELECT id , title FROM #__table name where published=1" multiple="single" key_field="id" value_field="title" class="inputbox" label="fieldlabel" description="fielddesc" required="true" />
</fieldset> 
</fields>
```

You can do this in another way as [custom field](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my question is can I do something like this?
I have a table with products and a table with shops associated to brands.
If I edit one shop I would like to show a combobox with all the products from the brand of the shop. Is that possible?

SELECT * FROM #__products WHERE brand = {the brand id associated to the shop I selected for edit} 

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

You can replace the query completely by doing the following:

1)Define you query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * from table_name WHERE table_id = '.$your_value;
```

2)Update your form field attribute:

```
$this->form->setFieldAttribute('field_name', 'query', $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue. After some digging I've figured out it is actually possible.

**1. Step - You need a custom form field: (I named it vssql.php)**

`JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('sql');`

```
class JFormFieldVSSQL extends JFormFieldSQL
{
    /**
     * The form field type.
     */
    public $type = 'VSSQL';

    /**
     * Overrides parent's method
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        // Get the ID
        $query_id = $this->form->getField((string) $this->element['query_id']);

        // Override query
        $this->element['query'] = str_replace('{query_id}', (string) $query_id->value, (string) $this->element['query']);

        return parent::getOptions();
    }
}
```

**2. Step - You need to know hot to use it:**

In you JForm xml add:

```
  <field
    name="field_name"
    type="vssql"
    query_id="user_id"
    query="SELECT id AS value, CONCAT(street,' ',city) AS addresses FROM #__addresses WHERE user_id = {query_id}"
    label="List of user addresses"
    required="required" />
```

In your SQL query the placeholder **{query_id}** will be replaced with the real value of parameter specified in **query_id**, which is *user_id* in this case. That will return a list of addresses from some table assigned to given user

Answer (score 1):

Some updates to @WooDzu solution:

```
class JFormFieldICategory extends JFormFieldSQL
{

    public $type = 'ICategory';

    /**
     * Overrides parent's method
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        // Get the ID
        $cat_id = $this->form->getField((string) $this->element['cat_id']);

        // Override query
        $this->query = str_replace('{cat_id}', (string) $cat_id->value, (string) $this->element['query']);
        echo $this->query.' test '; //exit();

        return parent::getOptions();
    }
```

}

Type should be public and query should be assign to $this->query.
Works great!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (I used this to select user plugins from #__extensions table) in Joomla 2.5+ and 3.x+) as WHERE condition:

```
<field name="plugin" type="sql" query="SELECT extension_id as value, name as title FROM #__extensions WHERE type = 'plugin' AND folder = 'user'" />
```

Comment: I think it's all about how to use variable in where clausule.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You cannot make where condition based on variable, only constant:(

BUT You can change the form field and reload the field in view with form->setField function. Thanks to this You can make any condition in field sql.

```
$NewFieldDefinition=new SimpleXMLElement('<field name="catid" type="sql" query="SELECT id, title FROM #__table WHERE title='.$condition.'" />');
$this->form->setField($NewFieldDefinition, null, true);
```